# Python: ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import script from my directory. Works for my partner but not for me

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm currently working on a project with a friend. We have a main script and a Functions script. In the main script the Functions are imported

```
import Functions
```

For my friend, everything works fine, for me I get ModuleNotFoundError No module named Functions. We work in a shared folder, and my os.getcwd() is our shared folder. We both use python 3.7 and we work in the same version of Spyder. What confuses me is that the code works perfect for others but not for me
Neither my teachers or fellow students have been able to help me.

Any ideas?

I've tried adding the folder in the PYTHONPATH manager.
I've tried reinstalling Spyder.
I've tried asking my teachers with no luck.
I've searched the internet.

Comment: Try to Import it with `import file_name_of_function.Functions`.

Comment: I have also faced this issue but not in the same context.you can import in two way if the script is in the same folder. First direct import script filename.and second with import .script name. another thing to notify please add __init__.py into the folder directory